# Ajax return status 200 but error callback executed: how to catch message from server for encoding to json?

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

My ajax request return status 200, but error callback is executed. This happens because command in php returns a message that is not json. For example, this happens when php try to unlink file without permissions (see code below). 
If the message was encoded to json, success callback was executed in ajax. I'd like to manage this message in success callback.
How to catch this message of no permissions for encoding to json, and prevent error callback is executed?

Here is the code.

siviglia.php

```
if ($_POST['action'] == 'cadice')
{
    $this->barcellona.php($_POST['filename']);
}

public function barcellona($filename)
{
    $u = unlink($filename);
    return $u;
}
```

madrid.js

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'siviglia.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            action: 'cadice',
            filename: 'fn',
        },
        success: function(response){
            alert("success");
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
```

If unlink return true, success callback is executed.
If "No permissions" message is thrown from linux, it is returned in browser console as `xhr.responseText` and status is 200. How to catch it in success callback?

Comment: use `is_writable()` on the file before delete

Comment: yes thank you i know; this is an example of what could cause the message but i actually would like to catch the message and manage in success callback. The problem is not "how to prevent this warning" but "there is a way to manage it in success callback?"

Comment: if the file is not writable then you throw back the message that file is not writtable

Comment: Ok thank you, so in general I have to manage any possible warning or error by php side, and there is no other way to manage it in success callback. Correct?

Comment: Manage them in server then display a meaningful message on client... not the error from the server... You don't want users to see server errors

Comment: thank you but the question is: there is no other way to manage warning message from server in success callback? Managing on server side is the only technical way possible?